# Como verificar erros em um XML

Tags: php, simplexml-load-string, simplexml

Estou utilizando a função `simplexml_load_string` para carregar um XML dinâmico, porém se existem erros de formatação neste XML ele só me retorna `false` e eu não sei aonde está o erro, é possível eu verificar isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar uma simples função para checar se o XML é valido.

```php
 <?php
function is_valid_xml ( $xml ) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

    $doc->loadXML( $xml );

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();

    return empty( $errors );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Segundo o [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php), se você carregar a biblioteca do [libxml](http://pt2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.libxml.php) consegue descobrir quais são os erros.

**Exemplo:**

```php
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");

if ($sxe === false) {

  echo "Erro carregando XML\n";

  foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo "\t", $error->message;
  }
}
?>
```